# Custom css style on hero card button in ms botframework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

Is it possible to have custom css style-sheet on Hero card's button in Microsoft bot framework.

here is my code

```
 string ImagePath = "file:\\" + HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("\\Images\\Like-icon_resize.png");
          string strStyle = "<style type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">" +
                    @"{
                        color:Red;
                      }                    
                    </style>";

List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
CardAction button = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "like",
    Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
    Image = strlike,
    Title = strStyle
};
cardButtons.Add(plButton);

HeroCard hero = new HeroCard()
{
        Text= "I'm a hero card",
        Buttons = cardButtons
};
```

and it displayed as [image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, HTML\CSS is not supported in bot framework since it needs to support multiple communication channels where most channels do not provide HTML support.

You can only use the controls provided to you by the framework (like image)